# Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

```
namespace exer4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnTotal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int overtime = Convert.ToInt32(txtHours.Text) - 30;
            int salary = Convert.ToInt32(txtHours.Text)*250;
            double tax = (salary + overtime) * .10;
            int deduction = salary - (300 + 400);

            //operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'
            if Convert.ToInt32(txtHours.Text > 30)
            {
                lblName.Text = txtName.Text;
                lblSalary.Text = Convert.ToString(overtime *120) + (salary - (deduction - tax)); 


            }
            else
            { 
                // //operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'
                lblSalary.Text = Convert.ToString(txtHours.Text) * 250;
            }
       }
  }
```

Comment: What do you expect the result of `* 250` on a string to be? What is the meaning of multiplying a string?

Comment: You just give us some code and that's it. Be specific. And also, how can you multiply a string?

Answer (score 4):

Your if statement should be

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(txtHours.Text) > 30)
```

And the other line should be

```
lblSalary.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(txtHours.Text) * 250);
```

Or better yet convert the txtHours text to an int and keep it in a variable to be reused.

```
    private void btnTotal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int hours = Convert.ToInt32(txtHours.Text);
        int overtime = hours - 30;
        int salary = hours * 250
        double tax = (salary + overtime) * .10;
        int deduction = salary - (300 + 400);

        if(hours > 30)
        {
            lblName.Text = txtName.Text;
            lblSalary.Text = ((overtime *120) + (salary - (deduction - tax))).ToString(); 
        }
        else
        { 
            lblSalary.Text = salary.ToString();
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to do:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(txtHours.Text) > 30)
{
    //normal code here
}
else
{
    //normal code
}
```

If first need to parse it as an int like you were doing then do the comparison so that the if can test a Boolean condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(txtHours.Text) > 30)
{ ...
```

Comment: Why a CW answer instead of, say, a comment?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Why not an answer? It is an answer and not a discussion isn't it?